# How can I get my folders back in a Visual Studio 2019 project?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019

I use Visual Studio 2019 (C++ project).

Because I got quite a lot of files, I split them in folders (just for viewing, on disk it seems one big folder).

However, as of today, in the Solution Explorer pane, I do not see any files anymore, but the message:

```
All items have been filtered from view.
```

What can I do to retrieve my folders/files in the Solution Explorer again?

Note, there is a Change View icon in the toolbar of the Solution Explorer. If I switch the view, I see all my files, but without any folder hierarchy (one big list of files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

- In the Solution Explorer toolbar is a button 'Show All Files' (third bottom from the right); select it.
- Change the view if necessary (fourth button from the left).

Answer (score 6):

Check if you have selected 'Pending changes filter (ctrl + [, P)' in solution explorer. It is icon with clock (by default 4th from left). If you have, then unselect it.

Comment: It's too long ago , but it might help others. Still upvoted.